# What is the type of comma separated variables?

Tags: python

I have this simple code:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> a, b
(1, 2)
```

Does this mean that the type is `tuple`? In not, then why the added parenthesis?

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning 1 to `a` and 2 to `b`.

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

If you want to check the type of a variable in Python, do:

```
type(a)
```

... which returns: `int`. I'd recommend you to read about [data structures and types](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), especially the section on tuples and sequences.

However, if you would do:

```
a, b = 1, 2
c = (a, b)

type(c)
```

The output is: `tuple`. You could also leave out the parentheses and do `c = a, b` which is also treated as a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. Then, I will read your resource.

Comment: @bananamonkey It's important to note that the OP did ***NOT*** do `c = (a, b)` but simply inspected `a, b` which is different and has reason for confusion. The main point here that variables separated by commas are *implicitly* treated as a tuple. Just like doing `return x, y` in a function returns a tuple (like Roy mentioned in their answer)

Comment: Okay. I'll reference it! Thank!

Answer (score 2):

If we test the below code:

```
a, b = 1,2
c = a, b
print(type(c))
```

it will print `tuple`.
In Python, if we put multiple values/variables separated by commas (with or without parenthesis) like above, that is considered as a tuple. That is the reason when you are trying to print the value of `a, b` you are getting the output in format of a tuple.